# how to handle empty input in python

Tags: python, list

I've a list where are stored the values of an input. I wanna that if the user skip the question the list get nan values.

I tried this:

```
sex=[]
sex.append(input("are you male or female?: "))
while not sex:
    sex.append(np.nan)
```

but doesn't work. I get this result:
    sex=['', '']

how can I handle this problem?

Comment: `while` is a loop, you need a conditional statement. But you already append whatever user inputted in the second line.

Comment: Read my second sentence. You are already appending to the list.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by nan?

kindly try this also:

```
sexArr = []
sexInp = input(">Are you male or female?")
if sexInp:
 sexArr.append(sexInp) 
print(sexArr)
```

Comment: good point i edited it